# Size of the Universe: Curved vs flat? Finite vs infinite?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, curvature, observable-universe

I have recently heard the theory that the Universe may be smaller than observed but may be curved to the extent that light rays may have looped past us once already and hence appear to have originated from further away than the source actually is located. If this is the case, would we not see light in every direction due to the fact that empty space would simply allow us to see fully around the curved universe to ourselves or other luminous objects? Would this same problem not present if the Universe were infinite?

Comment: Methods to measure the curvature of the universe have all come out saying it is flat.

Comment: Or at very least, too flat for this to be true

Comment: A flat universe can still be wrapped around. For example a torus. I think OP is using the word curved in that sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to the idea that if the universe was infinite in size and infinitely old, the sky would be as bright as the sun, since every point in the sky would end on a star, somewhere in the infinite universe. Since this is not the case, it led people to conclude that the universe is either finite in size or age.

Similarly, even if the universe was curved, as long at the curvature is sufficiently small, the light (curving around the universe on it's way to being seen by us) would not have had enough time to reach us. This agrees with experimental values that say that the universe is flat, within the error bars.

Astrophysicists have looked for repeating objects in the night sky in an attempt to confirm a curved universe, but failed to find anything. This means that the universe is not smaller than observed and curved, but does not rule out very small curvature, so that on a scale much larger than the observable universe we would see the light repeating.